# bbm package error

Tags: fonts, packages, errors

I am not sure if this should be here or whether I should create a bug report.  I am trying to use the `bbm` package as per this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
$\mathbbm{A}$
\end{document}
```

but I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./minimalbbm.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, uk
english, usenglishmax, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty)
(./minimalbbm.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/ubbm.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm bbm10
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for bbm10.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bbm10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2011)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf bbm10
! I can't find file `bbm10'.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bbm10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bbm10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: bbm10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bbm10' failed to make bbm10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font U/bbm/m/n/10=bbm10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.6 $\mathbbm{A}
                $
?
```

FYI: I am running Fedora with TeXlive 2011 installed manually and I have run

```
$ tlmgr install bbm-macros
```

but there is no poackage `bbm` available:

```
$ tlmgr search bbm
bbm-macros - LaTeX support for "blackboard-style" cm fonts.
```

It seems that this might be the problem.  In the Fedora TeXlive there is a package `texlive-bbm` and a package `texlive-bbm-macros` -- the former containing the cm-fonts.

Comment: I got this working by downloading the archive [here](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/bbm.tar.xz) and manually unpacking it into `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm` then running `tlmgr update --all`.

Comment: It would be nice if somebody with a manual install of TeXlive 2011 can confirm that the `bbm` package installs fine for them.  Then it must be just me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tlmgr show bbm` I get

```
package:     bbm
category:    Package
shortdesc:   "Blackboard-style" cm fonts.
```

so the `bbm` package exists.

I don't know much about Fedora, but if a `texlive-bbm` package exists, then that's what you have to install along with `bbm-macros`

I suggest you to do a complete install once and for all.

Comment: It could well be just me, see comment above.  Again it is a manual install of TL2011 from the TUG website, not from the Fedora repos.

Comment: @StephenMcAteer I always do a complete install. No reasons to spare a few hundred MiB.

Comment: And this is an install from the TUG website (as opposed to some repo)?  (I mean [this](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) one).

Comment: @StephenMcAteer Yes. I don't know much about Fedora packaging of TeX Live, but as the stand-alone distribution requires only setting the PATH variable and adds nothing else to the system directories, I vastly prefer it to packaged versions. Not to mention that Debian one has a two year backlog.

Comment: Then it must be just me.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to do a working install of `bbm` by

`$ tlmgr install bbm`

`$ tlmgr install bbm-macros`

Hope this helps. I'm running Mac OS X and installed TeXLive basic manually.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install bbm fonts. you can get the fonts from

http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bbm/

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: :( "After this operation, 1,074 MB of additional disk space will be used."